# Beginner Java reading text

Tags: java, io

I am completely new to java and just had my first college class for it. We havnt learned anything but I am trying to get a head start on the first assignment. I am trying to figure out how to read a text file than use that information to write a record to a different text file. To start i just am trying to read a text file this is what i have so far...Can you point me in the right direction.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class HomeWork1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String filename = "testing.txt";
    Scanner inputScanner;

    try{

    inputScanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(filename));
    String s = inputScanner.nextLine();

    System.out.printf("%s", s);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
    }



}

}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: Yeah, you've got most of the program here.  This will read a text file and write one line of its contents to the console.  So I guess your next step is to work out how to get it to write its contents to another file; and how to make it run over and over until the file has all been read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a Filereader if you are using a scanner you only need a File. So you can replace this line

```
inputScanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(filename));
```

by this

```
inputScanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));
```

As for this line

```
String s = inputScanner.nextLine();
```

You are reading one line only, you should do a loop to read every line.

```
while(inputScanner.hasNextLine()){
    String s = inputScanner.nextLine();
}
```

Your catch is not wrong but rather inaccurate, you are catching any exception without knowing exactly which exception happened. 
You should catch those exceptions instead,in order.

```
catch(NumberFormatException e){ 
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Whenever the program meets the first exception it will exit(reason why order matter),that is why you have to catch exceptions from the most specific to the most general.